# Can I use WebView without any javascript code?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm new to using WebView and I'm wondering, do I need to know javascript to use WebView to it's fullest potential?

For example if I want to interact with a website's actions like `post` or `reply` buttons, would I have to use javascript after creating my own buttons to add functionality to them?

In other words, if I don't like how these buttons on "www.example.com" look, can I hide them in my webview and add my own and then after adding my own, could I make them do what the websites buttons do, `post` or `reply` ? Would I need JS for this or could I do it all just using java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply show web pages in your application you need webview. If you want some external features to show something like javascript(e.g youtube videos) then you just need to enable some javascript features which are predefined.

If you need the web page operations like button click , playing with server database (like post as you want here) then you have to create the activity which holds the same design as the webpage (design through xml layout) and do whatever you want through java coding.

**Edit**

Just simply understand the current stackoverflow page. If you want to show this page in your app then you have to use a webview inside your layout and give the the current url inyour java code. But this is nothing but just the UI(user Interface). You can not do any kind of extra android operation in this because you simply show the desktop page in a mobile.

But if you want some extra operation to add then you have to create a personal xml layout same like the current stackoverflow page which has a tab on the top some hyperlinks on the right, some mutiline edittext views to write questions or answers and some more things.
Then you have to add each operations what stackoverflow does here and some extra if you need. If you want the same design then it depends on you..you may use So png images ,same writing style etc.. 
hope you understand.

Thank You

Comment: Thank you for replying Ranjit, could you please elaborate further on your second paragraph?

Could you explain that a bit further.

Comment: Thank you for that edit. I do understand.

I'm very relieved to hear that I don't have to use any javascript my self. I know I have to enable it probably but that's still all done though java code.

Thank's again.

Comment: @Dean Z dont worry. you can do every thing in android coding and also more user friendly. So Android is always great.